# Android change google map padding at runtime

Tags: android, google-maps, padding, inmobi

I want to move Google map layout items at runtime, but I'm not able to do it and I don't know if it's possible or not.
What I want to do is: I have a Google map fragment which takes up all the screen. I also have an Ad. When app starts, I show the map. Like this:

[image]

And when the ad loads, I show the ad at the bottom, but I need to move the Google logo above the ad. Like this:

[image]

I've tried with:

```
if (banner is loaded)
googleMap.setPadding(0, 0, 0, banner.getLayoutParams().height);
```

But I had no success. What am I doing wrong?

***EDIT:*** Thanks to @SimplePlan, I changed the RelativeLayout where was included the mapfragment to a FrameLayout:

```
<FrameLayout >
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

    <com.inmobi.monetization.IMBanner
        android:layout_gravity="bottom" />
</FrameLayout>
```

And I added a listener to the Ad:

```
banner.setIMBannerListener(new IMBannerListener() {
    @Override
    public void onBannerRequestSucceeded(IMBanner arg0) {
        googleMap.setPadding(0, 0, 0, banner.getLayoutParams().height);
    }
});
```

Comment: Put your `MapFragment`  and Ad in `FrameLayout` and set `Ad gravity` as `Bottom`

Comment: OK, it worked! I also had to set a banner listener (onBannerRequestSucceeded, I'm working with InMobi Ads) to know when the ad is loaded.

Answer (score 17):

As long as the layout process is not finished, the view's dimension is set to 0. Using `Handler`, you can set the map's padding after the layout is done.

```
    new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mapHelper.map.setPadding(0,0,0,ad.getHeight());
        }
    });
```

Comment: Just to clarify the padding parameters are `setPadding(left, top, right, bottom)`. I only add this because when I look at the actual method it lists the parameter names as `i`, `i1`, `i2`, `i3` which is super unhelpful.

Comment: @Markymark make sure to download "Sources for Android xx" in your Android SDK download manager to see javadoc and parameter names.

Comment: @sulai Sources for android does not include google map related code right? correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

We can now use KTX extensions to do some view logic after view load complete:

https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/core/view/package-summary#(android.view.View).doOnLayout(kotlin.Function1)

Answer (score 0):

Better way to do this is not to use FrameLayout and rather use **RelativeLayout** and put a relation that map should be above your banner. So whenever the banner appears your map will be accordingly moved up.

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_above="@id/banner"
        />

    <com.inmobi.monetization.IMBanner
        android:id="@+id/banner"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom" />
</RelativeLayout>
```