# How to fetch imageview co-ordinates(position/latlon) on google map

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-api-2

I have been trying to achieve this for a long time. But not being able to. So I did really need some help here with this.

Current method - refer the below image

[image]

like you see above, , marker image is an ImageView and is properly placed so that the tip of the marker is pointing to the center of the screen. And fetch a latlon I will be reading maps idle or move state and will use the below methods to get the latlons.

googleMap.getCameraPositionLatitude();
googleMap.getCameraPositionLongitude();

But, the real problem is with the below format which I want to achieve. because this would improve UI/UX as the view is placed in a place where user can view the location clearly to which he is pointing to clearly(of-course the bottom part of the screen would be filled up with suggestions or any further changes that I think of).

Please refer the below image -

[image]

Here I am stuck. i dont find any methods that provide me latlon from that portion of the screen. I really need help from you guys to solve this. i want to pull the location from where the tip of the view is pointing w.r.t the second image (above image). if I use googleMap.getCameraPositionLatitude();
googleMap.getCameraPositionLongitude(); Which is in appropriate as it will get me latlons from center of the screen.

kindly help me out with this !

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: why dont you use a draggable marker, and you center it on the center of the screen. then user can dragg the marker and get the lat/lng anywhere

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Map Padding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/map?hl=en#map_padding) for that. With [`.setPadding()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap#setPadding(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) method you can move map center to position what you need. Also take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22267814/6950238) question of [David](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1768231/david).