# Google logo is hide when add parallax effect between bottom sheet and mapView

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, android-coordinatorlayout, android-design-library, androiddesignsupport

I'm trying to add a parallel effect in between bottom sheet layout and map view.but google log in map view is hidden when expending the bottom sheet layout. [Google logo is hidden]

[show google logo when bottom sheet collapse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0zJs.jpg)

I'm using below code:

layout

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="@color/Green"
  tools:context=".ui.activities.ChooseLocationActivity">
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/map_rlyt"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="com.koya.android.ui.widget.CollapseBehavior"
    app:layout_anchor="@+id/bottom_sheet_layout">
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/g_map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/category_activity_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


  <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/category_search_box"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/custom_edit_text_margin_top"
      android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/custom_edit_text_margin_left_right"
      android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/custom_edit_text_margin_left_right"
      android:background="@android:color/transparent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/ic_back_iv"
        android:padding="@dimen/location_activity_back_button_padding"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_back_black"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="@dimen/custom_edit_text_padding"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:drawablePadding="8dp"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/ic_search_gray"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/edit_text_cursor_drawable"
        android:drawableRight="@mipmap/ic_close_gray"
        android:textSize="@dimen/custom_edit_text_text_size"
        android:background="@drawable/drawable_custom_edittext"
    />

  </LinearLayout>

  <ProgressBar
      android:id="@+id/progressBar"
      style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
      android:layout_centerInParent="true"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:visibility="gone"/>
  <Button
      android:id="@+id/redo_search_in_map_area_button"
      style="@style/CategoryChooseButtonStyle"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_below="@+id/category_search_box"
      android:layout_centerInParent="true"
      android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/fifteen_text_size"
      android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
      android:paddingEnd="@dimen/redo_search_button_padding"
      android:paddingStart="@dimen/redo_search_button_padding"
      android:text="@string/redo_search_in_map_area"
      android:textAllCaps="false"
      android:visibility="gone"
  />
</RelativeLayout>
<include
    android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet_layout"
    layout="@layout/bottom_sheet"/>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/select_location_button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:text="@string/use_selected_location"
    android:visibility="gone"
    tools:visibility="visible"
    style="@style/CategoryChooseButtonStyle"/>
<include android:id="@+id/error_layout"
    layout="@layout/error_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
/>
```

And Implement Coordinatorlayout.Behavior

```
public class CollapseBehavior<V extends ViewGroup> extends CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<V>{


  public CollapseBehavior(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
super(context, attrs);
  }

 @Override
  public boolean onDependentViewChanged(CoordinatorLayout parent, V child, View dependency) {
if (isBottomSheet(dependency)) {
    BottomSheetBehavior behavior = ((BottomSheetBehavior) ((CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) dependency.getLayoutParams()).getBehavior());

    int peekHeight = behavior.getPeekHeight();
    // The default peek height is -1, which
    // gets resolved to a 16:9 ratio with the parent
    final int actualPeek = peekHeight >= 0 ? peekHeight : (int) (((parent.getHeight() * 1.0) / (16.0)) * 9.0);
    if (dependency.getTop() >= actualPeek) {
        // Only perform translations when the
        // view is between "hidden" and "collapsed" states
        final int dy = dependency.getTop() - parent.getHeight();
        ViewCompat.setTranslationY(child, dy/2);
        return true;
    }
}

return false;
  }

  private static boolean isBottomSheet(@NonNull
  View view) {
final ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = view.getLayoutParams();
if (lp instanceof CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) {
    return ((CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) lp)
            .getBehavior() instanceof BottomSheetBehavior;
}
return false;
}


}
```

I need this type of scrolling in my application -->
https://streamable.com/g0tf9

How to scroll google map when bottom sheet expend with parallax effect? I would appreciate it a lot!

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android change google map padding at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22267814/android-change-google-map-padding-at-runtime)

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22267814/android-change-google-map-padding-at-runtime) question and answer.