# Java android move logo to the left top corner

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Hi I try move google logo on the left top corner I try do this :

```
googleMap.setPadding(0,10,0,0);
```

But all the time the logo is at the bottom

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22267814/android-change-google-map-padding-at-runtime+

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android change google map padding at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22267814/android-change-google-map-padding-at-runtime)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Relocate Google logo in MapView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6923472/relocate-google-logo-in-mapview)

Answer (score 0):

I referred from this link that says,

[How to hide Google logo from google maps by adding Overlaid image on google maps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33729066/how-to-hide-google-logo-from-google-maps-by-adding-overlaid-image-on-google-maps?noredirect=1&lq=1)

It shows that the developer doesn't have the privilege to relocate the Google logo so, kindly refer the google terms and conditions.

Comment: ok but I do not want hide this logo I want to move beacouse FloatingActionButton cover this logo

Comment: so can I move the google logo to the left by FloatingActionButton  width in this way?

Comment: Check the video out there


https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/map#map_padding

And Also check these link 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6923472/relocate-google-logo-in-mapview

Comment: So what can I do this?   googleMap.setPadding(fabShowList.getWidth(), 0, 0, 0);

Comment: And what I should to do ?